# Predict the polarity of the broken coil

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

[image]

When the north pole of a magnet is brought near a broken coil, then the current is in direction, A toB . Now, the coil should behave as a battery such that two ends of coil are +ve and -ve. Which end should be positive and negative?
My book says that: 
[image]
However, if the coil behaves as battery then current should flow from negative to positive terminal which implies A should be negative and B positive

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: To me the drawing is a bit ambiguous, which could further confuse the matter. It is not clear if the break is on the near or the far side of the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Current will be induced in the coil so that it opposes the relative motion between loop and magnet i.e the loop's face facing magnet would act as north pole.So the current would be anticlockwise from A to B. We consider the direction of current to be the direction of flow of positive charge. So current flows from positive end to negative end. What you are talking about is the electronic current.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity assume that in some way it is arranged that the rate of change of flux  through the loop and hence the induced emf is constant.

The induced conventional (positive charge) current does indeed flow anti-clockwise, from plate $A$ to plate $B$.

In doing so plate $B$ acquires a net positive charge and plate $A$ a net negative charge.
This sets up an electric field in the wire which opposes the motion of the charges due to the induced emf until there is no net movement of charges and hence no current in the loop.

What you now have is equivalent to looking inside a battery with plate $B$ as the positive terminal and plate $A$ as the negative terminal.
The “external circuit” is that non conducting bit between the two plates.
If a resistor is connected between the two plates to complete a conducting circuit then a current will flow through the resistor from plate $B$ to plate $A$.